# perl script does not close body?

Tags: html, perl, tags

In an example script that prints HTML, it looks to me that the body tag is not closed. However I have never had experience with Perl before. Is this example incorrect? or is there something else that means body is closed?

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>\n<head>\n<title>\nPerl CGI
Example\n</title>\n<body>\n<h1>Hello,
World!</h1>\nYour user agent is: <b>\n";
print $cgi_object->user_agent();
print "<b>.</html>\n";
```

Where there is a `.` on the last line it looks to me like it should be `</body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't missing anything, that code simply doesn't generate an end tag for the body element, but that tag (unlike the missing Doctype) is optional in HTML anyway so the element will be closed by the browser when it parses the end tag for the html element.

It would be better written something more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Template;

my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->header(-charset => 'utf-8');
my $ua = $cgi->user_agent();

my $tt = Template->new();

$tt->process(\*DATA, { ua => $ua });

__END__
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Perl CGI Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        <p>Your user agent is: <em>[% ua | html %]</em>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And better still if you ditched CGI and used [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/).

Comment: Here-documents would be another option for defining the text http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators